# @OneToMany JPA annotation causes unnecessary sql update and doesn't cascade

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I am migrating my app from xml based mapping to JPA annotation based mapping. But this fails only in a simple case. For example, I've the following 3 entities:

```
@Entitiy
public class UserAccount {

     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
     @JoinColumn(name = "user_account_id", nullable = false, 
                 insertable = true, updatable = false)
     @NotNull
     private Set<Authority> authorities;

     @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", nullable = false)

     ... get and setter
}

@Entity
public class Authority {

    @Column
    private String authority;

    ... get and setter
}

@Entity
public class User {
    ... some properties
}
```

If I create a new UserAccount instance and try to save it, I got an exception, because the Authority instance wasn't saved, which means, it doesn't cascade as it supposed to do.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient 
instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Authority ...
```

This happens, because hibernate tries to update the authority row (which wasn't inserted before):

```
Hibernate: 
    insert into users ...

Hibernate: 
    insert into user_accounts ...

Hibernate: 
    update authorities set user_account_id=? where id=?
```

I used the following service to save the UserAccount instance.

```
@Service
public class UserAccountService {

    @Resource
    private UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public void save(UserAccount userAccount) {

       userAccountRepository.save(userAccount);
    }

}
```

The strange thing is, that the User instance will be saved, so the OneToOne mapping cascades (if I remove the UserAccount.authorities property). But this worked with the xml based mapping (and without JPA). I ended up in calling a separate method to store the Authoriy instances.

```
@Service
public class UserAccountService {

    @Resource
    private UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;
    @Resource
    private AuthorityRepository authorityRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public void save(UserAccount userAccount) {

        userAccountRepository.save(userAccount);
        authorityRepository.save(userAccount.getAuthoritiesSet());
    }

}
```

Which means, I cascade manually... However, looking into the executed SQL statements, I can see, that hibernate inserts the authority instance and after that, it updates this row to set the UserAccount reference:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert into users ...

Hibernate: 
    insert into user_accounts ...

Hibernate: 
    insert into authorities (authority) values (?)

Hibernate: 
    update authorities set user_account_id=? where id=?
```

And for me this is a performance issue, because there are many authorities and I do not want to have 20 inserts and after that 20 updates. But I was not able to "remove" the updates and tell hibernate to set the user_account_id together with the authority.

Because I've many other objects having OneToMany relations, I am very interested in resolving this problem and appreciate your help and thoughts.

Hibernate: 4.3.4.Final,
spring data jpa: 1.5.1.RELEASE

Best regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

"**...object references an unsaved transient...**" means you have mapped a child object with a parent, and the child is not yet saved before you save a parent.

In your case you are saving the parent **UserAccount** along with child entity **Authorities** before saving **Authorities**.

You could create a OneToMany relation for authorities, with appropriate Cascade.

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private Set<Authority> authorities;
```

And if you have proper cascade, you need not have to save  the authorities separately like below line. You could remove it.

```
authorityRepository.save(userAccount.getAuthoritiesSet());
```

Comment: Hi Jay, but this is exactly what I've already done (look into my UserAccount object). That is really strange.

Comment: Ok try to remove all the parent/child mappings and add one by one and check where the problem starts.

Answer (score 0):

I solved both problems by downgrading the hibernate version to 4.2.11.Final. I don't know, why these problems occur in 4.3.4.Final. Maybe that's a problem in all 4.3.x versions!

Comment: is this still the solution to the problem? I'm currently facing similar issues.

Comment: Yes. I didn't try to upgrade to 4.3.5.Final yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar issue with ManyToOne mapping.
Solved problem by adding default value to version field.

```
@Version
@Column(name = "VERSION")
private Integer version = 1;
```