# Hibernate onetomany cascade not worked

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

`@OneToMany` and `CascadeType.All` does not work as I expected.

Here is my code.

The 'One' Side

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
    private long id;
    private User usersByUserId;
    private Collection<OrderBook> orderBooksById = new HashSet<>();

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    public User getUsersByUserId() {
        return usersByUserId;
    }

    public void setUsersByUserId(User usersByUserId) {
        this.usersByUserId = usersByUserId;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Collection<OrderBook> getOrderBooksById() {
        return orderBooksById;
    }

    public void setOrderBooksById(Collection<OrderBook> orderBooksById) {
        this.orderBooksById = orderBooksById;
    }
}
```

And the 'many' side.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_book")
public class OrderBook {
    private OrderBookPK pk = new OrderBookPK();
    private int num;

    @EmbeddedId
    public OrderBookPK getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(OrderBookPK pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public Book getBook(){
        return getPk().getBook();
    }

    public void setBook(Book book){
        getPk().setBook(book);
    }

    @Transient
    public Order getOrder(){
        return getPk().getOrder();
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order){
        getPk().setOrder(order);
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "num")
    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class OrderBookPK implements Serializable {
    private Order order;
    private Book book;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
    }
}
```

And I use this in my service.

```
@Transactional
public void addOrder(OrderFrom orderFrom) {
    Order order = new Order();
    User user = orderForm.getUser();
    order.setUsersByUserId(user);
    for (OrderFrom.OrderItem item: orderFrom.getOrderItems()){
        Book book = item.getBook();
        OrderBook orderBook = new OrderBook();

        orderBook.setOrder(order);
        orderBook.setBook(book);
        orderBook.setNum(item.getNumber());

        order.getOrderBooksById().add(orderBook);
    }
    orderDao.addOrder(order);
}
```

I expected it will save order as well as its children just as what cascade intended. But when I run it, only order is saved with no exception throwed.

```
Hibernate: insert into orders (user_id, id) values (?, ?)
```

I searched on the Internet and found [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496548/hibernate-insert-cascade-not-inserting-foreign-key), but not worked for my situation.

Comment: which hibernate version are you using?

Comment: and why the strange names? Why call it "usersByUserId" although "user" would be more appropriate?

Comment: have you tried oderDao.persist(oderBook) before orderDao.addOrder(order)?

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher It's generated by tools. I'm using hibernate 4.3.5. I tried `persist(orderBook)` before add, but it seems hibernate trying to save the orderBook with `order_id=0` which throws reference key error.

Comment: somewhat related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108644/onetomany-jpa-annotation-causes-unnecessary-sql-update-and-doesnt-cascade and he downgraded hibernate to fix the problem. Maybe that's worth a try. Other than that: sorry, can't help

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher Thanks. It turns out still not working for me.